# How to get a context path of a properties file from a webservice in java?

Tags: java, web-services, file, contextpath

I am trying read the context path of a properties file from my application,

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));



import java.util.Properties;

public class test1 {

    public String getValues()
    {
        PropertiesFileReader fileReader = new PropertiesFileReader();

        Properties prop = fileReader.getProp("/messages/AttachFile.properties");

        String out = prop.getProperty("FILE_NAME");

        return out;
    }
}
```

This works when the properties file is under `WEB-INF -> classes -> messages -> myfile`
but when i move this file to some other folder like `WEB-INF -> messages -> myfile` it doesn't seem to get the path...

EDIT: I am not using servlets...

Comment: mebbe its just a classpath issue. try adding the other folders in the classpath and see if its alright

Comment: @govi no its not getting me there... Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

If fails because the new path is not part of the classpath while `Class#getResourceAsStream()` loads resources from the classpath. The `/WEB-INF/classes` is by default part of the classpath as specified in the Servlet API specification, that's why it worked. I recommend to keep it in the classpath or to add the new path `/WEB-INF/resources` to the classpath.

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, then you can do it by adding it as *Source Folder* in project's build path (which would during build move it back into the `/WEB-INF/classes` anyway). Alternatively, you can also just create a `resources` package in the Java source root and then put the file there. It will become part of the classpath as well.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to prepend `/WEB-INF/`:

```
"/WEB-INF/messages/myfile";
```

Comment: i want it without servlet context because i am not using servlets

Comment: well I suggest you using Maven with Maven Resources Plugin

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are not using servlets, what do you mean? How this code runs?
Basically, when you do use servlets, only WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib are on the classpath. So you cannot access the resources using classloaders. BUT you can access them using the ServletContext. So assuming your code runs in Servlet/JSP, you can do the following:

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("your resource starting from web-application root");
```